# CMake :Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

I am currently trying to compile a project in CMake 3.10.0 and it keeps giving the above error box and this

```
    The C compiler identification is unknown
    The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
        No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
        No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



    Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I am currently running Microsoft Visual Studio 15 2017 and when I am configuring it, I am using x64.

Answer (score 9):

i had same problem when using vs 2015 but after installing vs 2017 it solved. I think you should repair your visual studio 2017 and try again.
if cmake don`t let you configure with new vs in file tab clear use "delete cache" and try again

Comment: In CMake 3.14, "delete cache" is under the `File` tab

Answer (score 4):

When you installed Visual Studio 2017, did you install the Visual C++ compilers? It's not enabled by default. Go to Add or Remove programs and try Repairing/Modifying it to make sure Visual C++ is included.

---

This is going to sound like a stupid suggestion but if you've just installed VS 2017, make sure you're actually able to compile a sample C++ solution. Yes, you would be surprised by the amount of people I've seen with this error that simply didn't realize their compiler wasn't installed.

---

My third suggestion would be to try opening the x86 or x64 Native Tools Command Prompt and try running your CMake build again. The problem, as I'm sure you've noticed haha, is that it can't find your C compilers. Running these Command Prompts will ensure your correct environment variables are set. If this fails, your C compilers are missing and you need to re-install VS2017. If this *works* that means there's an issue with your environment PATH.

Comment: thanks for responding, I've tried the first 2 solutions to no success, how do I go about the 3rd solution?

Comment: When you say with no success, do you mean that you were actually able to build a c++ program in Visual Studio and CMake is still not working? 
@shaddles Or do you mean you weren't able to build a C++ program and therefore CMake is not working as well? As far as the third suggestion, to open the Visual Studio Command prompts you just go to: **Start > Visual Studio 2017 > x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017** (or **x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017**)

Comment: I was able to build a C++ program in Visual Studio, also just tried to configure the build while the command prompt was open and I am still getting the same error

Comment: @shaddles Hmm... Interesting. I remember one of my coworkers having the same issue a few years ago but I can't remember what he/I did to resolve it.. Another stupid question for you. CMake isn't installed on a separate drive is it? If it isn't, try uninstalling CMake completely and use a 3.6.x version - 64 bit install. When installing, make sure to install for all users (so that it adds it to your system PATH).

Comment: Downloaded and installed 3.6.x but it doesn't allow me to configure with the current version of Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @shaddles Crap, that was my mistake. I meant 3.7.2, that was the version that introduced 2017.

Comment: I reset my Laptop and CMake is able to find the compiler now but there are now new issues with OpenSG which I will put in a seperate thread. Thank you

Comment: Ah.. The old fashioned "Have you tried turning it off and back on again?"

Answer (score 3):

First step， Click the File, select Delete Cache, Second step, Click the Configure, select the VS15 2017, then Done.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To Solve the problem, I just downloaded the last version of the ***opencv*** and ***opencv_contrib*** repositories(both on the same branch named '3.4').

Answer (score 0):

Another version of this error occurred in my case when I wanted to build librealsense from source using cmake, in my case the silly error was providing the source code path in librealsense E:\librealsense-2.49.0\src rather i should have provided E:\librealsense-2.49.0 alone. this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I hadn't selected the correct visual studio version in the configuration panel. Once I did that everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you named `CMakeLists.txt` correctly. Once I omitted a 's' at the end of the list, so I got the same error. But when I added 's' it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking if I can compile a C++ program and rechecking my Visual Studio components, updating my windows SDK to the new version,  I installed a another version of Cmake and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat**: This perhaps too obvious and facile to even post, but since @N.S's answer made me think to try it, and it worked...

MacOS only: (using 13.1)

- Problem: Outdated version of CMake not used for a long time causing this error. Has been impossible to fix.
- Solution: Downloaded newest CMake, replacing outdated CMake. Working.

Xcode 14.2